# Common misconception : Files have an EOF char at their end

Tags: c, file, eof

I was reading "PC assembly language by Carter" and I saw this phrase in footnote of page 32 which made me so confused !
If we assume that files may have not EOF at their end (as the book says) is a correct statement, then how can we figure out where is end of a file ?
 
and it also arises another question : does fseek use EOF to go back and forth in file ?

Comment: All files have a size. If you read from the first byte until the last (as indicated by the file size) you have reached the end of the file. No special _character_ marks the end of the file (think about trying to read binary data, how would the end-of-file byte differ from any other byte?).

Comment: The confusion might be that EOF by itself is simply short for "End Of File", and as such it can mean lots of things: the ASCII character 0x1A, the condition where an open file reader had reached the end, the function `eof()` or its result, the non-character constant `EOF` etc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just for fun, you should create a text file with a \x1A in the middle and then `type` it from the command line.

Comment: @MrLister I know, in Windows reading from text files checks for `CTRL-Z` (i.e. the byte `0x1a`) as a special end-of-file character. Doesn't make it a _real_ end of file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, but I'm afraid that's where much of the confusion comes from. You _can_ have an EOF character which is stored in a file and which flags an EOF, even if its ASCII name isn't "EOF"!

Comment: The 0x1A byte is a terrible, painful [source of agony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483711/serialdata-eof-circumstances).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PC => ^Z : EOF

in the olde PC-days the ctrl-Z was the signal in a file for EOF.

under UNIX and other modern systems: after reading behind the stat.st_size, EOF is signalled

Answer (score 6):

From [http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20170602065148/http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php):

> What is this value?   EOF   A common misconception of students is that
>   files have a special EOF character at the end. There is no special
>   character stored at the end of a file. EOF is an integer error code
>   returned by a function.

Comment: That only tells me these people don't know about ^Z.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `EOF` is not stored at the end of the file, and is not `char`. `EOF` is an error message, that read functions return when there is not more data to read. This is the reason that `getchar` returns `int` - it may return a `char` converted to `int`, or the `int` `EOF` (which is not valid `char`, so if you got it, you can be sure that you passed the end of file).

Comment: This is the most illuminating answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

EOF is not stored in the file. EOF (usually defined as -1) is returned by OS when there's no more data to read or an input error occurred. So once you reach the end of file, you *must* hit EOF.

My guess about the statement in your book is it meant `"EOF is not necessarily be at the end of file but also possible to have it somewhere in the middle of a file".` This is true on expected input error.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of C code, `EOF` is simply an indication that there is no more data available for a given input stream.  Whether that corresponds to a special EOF character in the file itself is a function of the underlying file or I/O system.